# transpose sub-blocks of numpy array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a Numpy array which consists of several square sub-blocks. For example:

```
A = [A_1 | A_2 | ... A_n],
```

each of them has the same size. I would like to transpose it in the following way:

```
B = [A_1^T | A_2^T| ... A_n^T].
```

Is there a way to do it instead of slicing the original array and then transposing each sub-block?

Comment: Why slicing+transposing each sub-block does not fit your needs? This is the standard way of doing that in Numpy. It may not be efficient for small block due to CPython calls but this is the price to pay for using a slow interpreter. If you do not want to pay such overhead, then you need to use a compiled implementation (using Cython, C extensions, Numba, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `A_i` has shape (M, M), I can see two scenarios:

1. Your entire array `A` is already in shape (N, M, M). In this case, you can transpose the submatrices `A_i` using [`np.ndarray.swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.swapaxes.html) or [`np.ndarray.transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html). Example:

```
A = np.arange(36).reshape(4, 3, 3)

# 4 submatrices A_0 ... A_3 each with shape (3, 3)
# array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
#         [ 3,  4,  5],
#         [ 6,  7,  8]],
# 
#        [[ 9, 10, 11],
#         [12, 13, 14],
#         [15, 16, 17]],
# 
#        [[18, 19, 20],
#         [21, 22, 23],
#         [24, 25, 26]],
# 
#        [[27, 28, 29],
#         [30, 31, 32],
#         [33, 34, 35]]])

B = A.swapaxes(1, 2)

# The submatrices are transposed:
# array([[[ 0,  3,  6],
#         [ 1,  4,  7],
#         [ 2,  5,  8]],
# 
#        [[ 9, 12, 15],
#         [10, 13, 16],
#         [11, 14, 17]],
# 
#        [[18, 21, 24],
#         [19, 22, 25],
#         [20, 23, 26]],
# 
#        [[27, 30, 33],
#         [28, 31, 34],
#         [29, 32, 35]]])
```

2. Your entire array `A` has only two dimensions, i.e. shape (M, N * M). In this case, you can bring your array to three dimensions first, then swap the axes, and then shape your array back to 2 dimensions. Example:

```
A = np.arange(36).reshape(3, 12)

# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
#        [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
#        [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
# A_i:    ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^

B = A.reshape(3, 4, 3).swapaxes(0, 2).reshape(3, 12)

# array([[ 0, 12, 24,  3, 15, 27,  6, 18, 30,  9, 21, 33],
#        [ 1, 13, 25,  4, 16, 28,  7, 19, 31, 10, 22, 34],
#        [ 2, 14, 26,  5, 17, 29,  8, 20, 32, 11, 23, 35]])
# A_i^T:  ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Interesting solution, though I think it worth it if the indices do not need to be recomputed every time (eg. to transpose an array in a loop doing many transposition on array of the same shape). Otherwise the solution will be inefficient (due to both the strides and indirect indexing) and things like Numba/Cython would be much better than using Numpy.